# Put search bar in nav bar programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, searchbar

I am trying to place a search bar in a navigation bar using the following code:

```
  UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
    searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    UIView *searchBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 310.0, 44.0)];
    searchBarView.autoresizingMask = 0;
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    [searchBarView addSubview:searchBar];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBarView;
```

It does place the search bar in the nav bar but does not cover the buttons on either side.  It also does not have a cancel option.

[image]

I would prefer to have it look like this:

[image]

Can anyone suggest how to adjust the above code to do that?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: The result you are trying to achieve, visually looks more like `UISearchController` (or `UISearchDisplayController` prior iOS 8) being presented after user taps some mock search bar or other UI element. See [this sample code from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html). Anyways, I would love to see what others are up to.

Comment: The sample from apple uses ios9.  Is placing the search bar in the nav bar not possible from 7.0 onwards?

Comment: I believe things not changed in terms of what you could put into navigation bar, since iOS 7. What I'm saying is that possible solution to what you are trying to achieve could be putting custom `UITextField` in the nav bar, and when user taps on it, a search controller is presented.

Answer (score 0):

in One of my project i did the same using below code hope it will help you :

```
-(void)addSearchBar{
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, -10, 285, 64)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems=nil;

    [self.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES];
    for (id subView in ((UIView *)[self.searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).subviews) {
        NSLog(@"subView====%@", subView);
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *textField = subView;
            textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
            break;
        }
        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){

            UIButton* cancelBtn = (UIButton*)subView;
            cancelBtn.frame=CGRectMake(cancelBtn.frame.origin.x, cancelBtn.frame.origin.x, 30, 30);
            [cancelBtn setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cancelBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_cancel_h.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cancelBtn setEnabled:YES];
        }
    }

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

            self.searchBar.delegate=self;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.searchBar];
}
```